# Getting NoReverseMatch error when trying to redirect user after form upload

Tags: python, django, redirect

I am getting the error `NoReverseMatch` in Django when I try to redirect the user to a new URL after processing a form upload and successfully saving the form.
Here is my `views.py`

```
@login_required
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        profile_form = UpdateProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
        files = request.FILES.getlist('resume')
        resumes_data = []
        if profile_form.is_valid():
            for file in files:
                try:
                    # saving the file
                    resume = profile_form.cleaned_data['resume']

                    parser = ResumeParser(file.temporary_file_path())
                    data = parser.get_extracted_data()
                    resumes_data.append(data)
                    profile_form.instance.name = data.get('name')
                    profile_form.instance.email              = data.get('email')
                    profile_form.instance.mobile_number      = data.get('mobile_number')
                    if data.get('degree') is not None:
                        profile_form.instance.education      = ', '.join(data.get('degree'))
                    else:
                        profile_form.instance.education      = None
                        profile_form.instance.company_names      = data.get('company_names')
                        profile_form.instance.college_name       = data.get('college_name')
                        profile_form.instance.designation        = data.get('designation')
                        profile_form.instance.total_experience   = data.get('total_experience')
                    if data.get('skills') is not None:
                        profile_form.instance.skills         = ', '.join(data.get('skills'))
                    else:
                        profile_form.instance.skills         = None

                    if data.get('experience') is not None:
                        profile_form.instance.experience     = ', '.join(data.get('experience'))
                    else:
                        profile_form.instance.experience     = None
                    profile_form.save()
                    return redirect('users-profile')
                except IntegrityError:
                    messages.warning(request, 'Duplicate resume found')
                    return redirect('users-profile')
                
        profile_form.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Your profile is updated successfully')
        # return redirect(reverse('userprofile', kwargs={"id": request.user}))
        return redirect('userprofile')
    else:
        profile_form = UpdateProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    return render(request, 'user/resumeprofile.html', {'profile_form': profile_form})

@login_required
def myprofile(request, user_id):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(id=user_id)
    context = {'profile':profile}
    return render(request, 'user/profile.html', context)
```

And here is my `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', jobs_views.home, name='home'),   #this is home function inside the views.py in the jobs folder
    path('contact',jobs_views.contact, name='contact'),
    # path('jobs/', jobs_views.job_list, name='job-list'),
    path('jobs/<slug:slug>', jobs_views.job_detail, name='job_detail'), #slug will help us identify the specific instance of job

    path('jobs-search/', jobs_views.job_search, name='job_search'),
    path('profile/', jobs_views.profile, name='users-profile'),
    path('userprofile/<int:user_id>',jobs_views.myprofile, name='userprofile')

]
```

The error occurs when I redirect the user to `userprofile` but I don't get any error when I redirect them to `users-profile`. Attached is a screenshot of the error message displayed. [The Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCJYX.png)

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: change  `return redirect(reverse('userprofile', kwargs={"id": request.user}))` to `return redirect(reverse('userprofile', kwargs={"id": self.request.user.id}))`

Comment: And then where will I import the self attribute from? Sorry I am still new to django

Comment: I am getting this error `NameError at /profile/
name 'self' is not defined`

Comment: try with `request.user.id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go around it by just taking the user id from the request since they are required to be logged in.

In your `urls.py` paths, change the path `userprofile` to :

```py
path('userprofile/',jobs_views.myprofile, name='userprofile') # remove id parameter
```

Then in your `myprofile` view, change to:

```py
@login_required
    def myprofile(request):
        user_id = request.user.id
        profile = Profile.objects.get(id=user_id)
        context = {'profile':profile}
        return render(request, 'user/profile.html', context)
```